# Azure Group Authentication MVC

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory

I have an MVC solution I have built in Visual Studio 2015 Pro. I have setup the solution to use Azure Authentication to authenticate against our Azure Active Directory. The authentication works to allow only those in our Active Directory in, however when we limit access to a Controller to a specific security group it appears to work when running from Visual Studio, however when we deploy to our IIS server, it does not work. We proceeded to return the (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal object and running through Visual Studio (F5) we see all the groups returned. When we look at the server, it matches what we saw locally, however groups are blank. Any ideas how to fix this? Code below shows how we captured the ClaimsPrincipal.

```
var Identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal; 
            var newCLAIM = Identity.Claims;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in newCLAIM)
            {
                sb.Append(item.Type.ToString());
                sb.Append(" : ");
                sb.Append(item.Value.ToString());
                sb.Append(" ;; ");
            }
```

Comment: Is the local version and server version using same Azure AD app registration? If you are using different values for clientId/ApplicationId in those two places (i..e pointing to different app registrations), then make sure that the the second application registration manifest also has `"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"` mentioned in it.. If that is missing in manifest, group claims will be missing.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, we are using 2 different Applications but the Manifests both have "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"

Comment: If you have 2 applications, with one working perfectly while other is not with essentially same code (unless there is a difference).. I definitely advise taking the two json manifests side by side and compare them (may be use a tool to do text comparison in two files).. I have even seen cases where same attribute "groupMembershipClaims" was specified more than once in the same manifest with different values and that was causing issue in getting group claims at run time..

Comment: So we went ahead and did a little test and re-pointed our local to point to the application the server uses, groups come in just fine. Could the issue be an IIS configuration issue on the server? or possibly a firewall issue?